# How to export a List as Web Part?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, custom-list

I am trying to export a customized list from SharePoint 2013 as web part and import into a site so it can be reused.

But couldn't figure out how to do that, there is no export option when I checked the property of this list.

I am viewing the list from this kind of URL:

```
http://intranet/en-us/Lists/TestList_Contacts/AllItems.aspx
```

Should I go to the LIST tab in the ribbon to form a web part or I only can export as an Excel?

Answer (score 2):

- open list settings
- click save list as template

[image]

- in the site , click site settings , add new app , add new list from the new template

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to add the List like a web part, where I can select from the Ribbon menu like Content Search etc.?

Answer (score 1):

From list setting Save the List as Template (If you need content also then check the box)

Download the `stp` file

Open the site settings of the target site -> List Template Gallery -> Upload the STP File

Now you can create a new List using the template you have uploaded.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to add the List like a web part, where I can select from the Ribbon menu like Content Search etc.?

Comment: Yes once you add the list template to the gallery - you need to create a list instance.. and then you will be able to add it to any page.

Comment: Thank you. Basically this List is specifically for this site, I just try to make it available to any future using. For the page I am working on, everything is within a web part of a Web Part Zone. So I would  need to add a List Web Part from the Apps category I guess. For creating a list instance, that would require Visual Studio to create a project and some coding?